# matching string for regexp

Tags: regex

is there a way to find a matching string which start with "/pathA/pathB/". 
For example: console.log(matches) for the following string

```
"/pathA/pathB/c/d" ,"/pathA/pathB/e/f"
```

but doesn't console.log for the following string

```
'C/pathA/pathB" or "D/E/pathB/pathA"
```

I have tried the following

```
var reg = new RegExp $^(/pathA/pathB) 
if(string.match(reg))
{ console.log("it matches"). }
```

but couldn't

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: Thanks! that solve it